# Evaluate performance of DLL calls from VBA

Tags: performance, vba, excel, winapi

While playing with a [VBA project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252659/fast-native-memory-manipulation-in-vba)  involving Windows APIs, I have noticed some odd behavior: API calls under Excel 2016/VBA7/x64 appeared to be much slower than under Excel 2002/VBA6/x32. Since I wanted to follow the recipe described in the [Weak Reference](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/lazy-object-weak-reference/) post, I decided to look into this performance matter more closely.

#### DLL side: Mock DLL library with test fixtures and a C-client

To simplify the interpretation of results, I created a small C-based dll with several stubs (memtools.c shown below) and a C-based client calling this dll and timing the calls (memtoolsclient.c). This C-code to C-code call timings provide performance references. The DLL includes five stubs. The first function, PerfGauge, takes a loop counter, times execution of an empty For loop within the DLL, and returns the result. The remaining stubs permit timing the dll calls and examine differences associated with passing arguments and returning a value. As their names suggest, these stubs

- are either a Sub or Function and
- take either zero or three arguments.

**memtools.c**

```c
#include "memtools.h"

// Volatile loop counter should be used here to prevent optimization.
MEMTOOLSAPI int MEMTOOLSCALL PerfGauge(unsigned int ForCount) {
  struct timeb start, end;
  ftime(&start);
  for (volatile unsigned int i=0; i < ForCount; i++) {
    ;
  }
  ftime(&end);
  return 1000 * (end.time - start.time) + (end.millitm - start.millitm);
}

MEMTOOLSAPI void MEMTOOLSCALL DummySub0Args() {
  return;
}

MEMTOOLSAPI void MEMTOOLSCALL DummySub3Args(void* Destination, const void* Source, size_t Length) {
  return;
}

MEMTOOLSAPI int MEMTOOLSCALL DummyFnc0Args() {
  volatile int Result = 10241024;
  return Result;
}

MEMTOOLSAPI int MEMTOOLSCALL DummyFnc3Args(void* Destination, const void* Source, size_t Length) {
  volatile int Result = 10241024;
  return Result;
}
```

**memtools.h**

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <string.h> 

#ifndef MEMTOOLS_H
#define MEMTOOLS_H

#ifdef _WIN32

  /* You should define MEMTOOLS_EXPORTS *only* when building the DLL. */
  #ifdef MEMTOOLS_EXPORTS
    #define MEMTOOLSAPI __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define MEMTOOLSAPI __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif

  /* Define calling convention in one place, for convenience. */
  #define MEMTOOLSCALL __stdcall

#else /* _WIN32 not defined. */

  /* Define with no value on non-Windows OSes. */
  #define MEMTOOLSAPI
  #define MEMTOOLSCALL

#endif /* _WIN32 */

/* Make sure functions are exported with C linkage under C++ compilers. */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Declare our function using the above definitions. */
MEMTOOLSAPI  int MEMTOOLSCALL PerfGauge(unsigned int ForCount);
MEMTOOLSAPI void MEMTOOLSCALL DummySub0Args();
MEMTOOLSAPI void MEMTOOLSCALL DummySub3Args(void*, const void*, size_t);
MEMTOOLSAPI  int MEMTOOLSCALL DummyFnc0Args();
MEMTOOLSAPI  int MEMTOOLSCALL DummyFnc3Args(void*, const void*, size_t);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif

#endif /* MEMTOOLS_H */
```

**memtoolsclient.c**

```c
#include "memtools.h"

void DummySub0ArgsGauge();
void DummySub3ArgsGauge();
void DummyFnc0ArgsGauge();
void DummyFnc3ArgsGauge();

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
  DummySub0ArgsGauge();
  DummySub3ArgsGauge();
  DummyFnc0ArgsGauge();
  DummyFnc3ArgsGauge();
  return 0;
}

void DummySub0ArgsGauge() {
  void (*volatile MEMTOOLSCALL pDummySub0Args)();
  pDummySub0Args = DummySub0Args;
  struct timeb start, end;
  ftime(&start);
  for (volatile int i=0; i < 1e9; i++) {
    pDummySub0Args(); 
  }
  ftime(&end);
  const int MSEC_IN_SEC = 1000;
  int diff;
  diff = MSEC_IN_SEC * (end.time - start.time) + (end.millitm - start.millitm);
  printf("\nDummySub0Args - 1e9 times - %u milliseconds\n", diff);
}

void DummySub3ArgsGauge() {
  char Src[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPGRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPGRSTUVWXYZ";
  char Dst[255];
  size_t SrcLen = sizeof(Src);
  struct timeb start, end;
  ftime(&start);
  for (volatile int i=0; i < 1e9; i++) {
    DummySub3Args(Dst, Src, SrcLen);
  }
  ftime(&end);
  const int MSEC_IN_SEC = 1000;
  int diff;
  diff = MSEC_IN_SEC * (end.time - start.time) + (end.millitm - start.millitm);
  printf("\nDummySub3Args - 1e9 times - %u milliseconds\n", diff);
}

void DummyFnc0ArgsGauge() {
  int Result __attribute__((unused));
  struct timeb start, end;
  ftime(&start);
  for (volatile int i=0; i < 1e9; i++) {
    Result = DummyFnc0Args(); 
  }
  ftime(&end);
  const int MSEC_IN_SEC = 1000;
  int diff;
  diff = MSEC_IN_SEC * (end.time - start.time) + (end.millitm - start.millitm);
  printf("\nDummyFnc0Args - 1e9 times - %u milliseconds\n", diff);
}

void DummyFnc3ArgsGauge() {
  char Src[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPGRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPGRSTUVWXYZ";
  char Dst[255];
  size_t SrcLen = sizeof(Src);
  int Result __attribute__((unused));
  struct timeb start, end;
  ftime(&start);
  for (volatile int i=0; i < 1e9; i++) {
    Result = DummyFnc3Args(Dst, Src, SrcLen);
  }
  ftime(&end);
  const int MSEC_IN_SEC = 1000;
  int diff;
  diff = MSEC_IN_SEC * (end.time - start.time) + (end.millitm - start.millitm);
  printf("\nDummyFnc3Args - 1e9 times - %u milliseconds\n", diff);
}
```

---

#### VBA side: DllPerfLib class with VBA fixtures

The DllPerfLib VBA class calls these stubs and times them. Out of curiosity, I also added VBA stubs with signatures matching those in the dll so that DllPerfLib also times calls to these stubs yielding performance of native calls. DllPerfLib includes several blocks. The first block starting from the top contains dll stub declarations, factory, constructor, and attribute accessors. The second block handles dll loading from the project directory via the [DllManager](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/268630/) class. Then follows a wrapper for the performance reference routine (empty timed For loop inside the dll). The next block includes four functions, timing calls to corresponding dll stubs and their VBA twins defined in the last section of the class.

**DllPerfLib.cls**

```vb
'@Folder "DllManager.Demo.Custom and Extended DLL.DLL Call Performance"
'@ModuleDescription "Provides utilities for guaging performance of DLL calls via the memtools DLL."
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit

Private Const LIB_NAME As String = "DllManager"
Private Const PATH_SEP As String = "\"
Private Const LIB_RPREFIX As String = _
    "Library" & PATH_SEP & LIB_NAME & PATH_SEP & _
    "Demo - DLL - STDCALL and Adapter" & PATH_SEP

Public Enum TargetTypeEnum
    TARGET_DLL = 0&
    TARGET_VBA = 1&
End Enum

#If Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub DummySub0Args Lib "MemToolsLib" ()
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub DummySub3Args Lib "MemToolsLib" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DummyFnc0Args Lib "MemToolsLib" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DummyFnc3Args Lib "MemToolsLib" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PerfGauge Lib "MemToolsLib" (ByVal ForCount As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Sub DummySub0Args Lib "MemToolsLib" ()
Private Declare Sub DummySub3Args Lib "MemToolsLib" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
Private Declare Function DummyFnc0Args Lib "MemToolsLib" () As Long
Private Declare Function DummyFnc3Args Lib "MemToolsLib" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function PerfGauge Lib "MemToolsLib" (ByVal ForCount As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Type TDllPerfLib
    DllMan As DllManager
    DummyForCount As Long
    GaugeForCount As Long
    PrintToImmediate As Boolean
    Src() As Byte
    Dst() As Byte
    SrcLen As Long
End Type
Private this As TDllPerfLib


Public Function Create( _
            Optional ByVal DummyForCount As Long = 10000000, _
            Optional ByVal GaugeForCount As Long = 10000000) As DllPerfLib
    Dim Instance As DllPerfLib
    Set Instance = New DllPerfLib
    Instance.Init DummyForCount, GaugeForCount
    Set Create = Instance
End Function

Friend Sub Init(Optional ByVal DummyForCount As Long = 10000000, _
                Optional ByVal GaugeForCount As Long = 10000000)
    With this
        .DummyForCount = DummyForCount
        .GaugeForCount = GaugeForCount
        .PrintToImmediate = True
    End With
    Set this.DllMan = DllManager.Singleton
    If DllManager.Singleton Is Nothing Then LoadDlls

    this.Src = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPGRSTUVWXYZ"
    this.Dst = String(255, "_")
    this.SrcLen = (UBound(this.Src) - LBound(this.Src) + 1 + Len(vbNullChar)) * 2
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    UnLoadDlls
End Sub

Public Property Get DummyForCount() As Long
    DummyForCount = this.DummyForCount
End Property

Public Property Let DummyForCount(ByVal Value As Long)
    this.DummyForCount = Value
End Property

Public Property Get GaugeForCount() As Long
    GaugeForCount = this.GaugeForCount
End Property

Public Property Let GaugeForCount(ByVal Value As Long)
    this.GaugeForCount = Value
End Property

Public Sub TogglePrint()
    this.PrintToImmediate = Not this.PrintToImmediate
End Sub

'''' ==================== HANDLE DLL LOADING ==================== ''''

Private Sub LoadDlls()
    Dim DllPath As String
    DllPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & PATH_SEP & LIB_RPREFIX & "memtools\" & ARCH
    Dim DllName As String
    DllName = "MemToolsLib.dll"
    Set this.DllMan = DllManager.Create(DllPath, DllName, True)
End Sub

Private Sub UnLoadDlls()
    this.DllMan.ForgetSingleton
    this.DllMan.FreeMultiple
    Set this.DllMan = Nothing
End Sub

'''' ==================== PERFORMANCE GAUGE WRAPPER ==================== ''''

Public Function PerfGaugeGet(Optional ByVal GaugeForCount As Long = -1) As Long
    Dim GaugeMax As Long
    GaugeMax = IIf(GaugeForCount > 0, GaugeForCount, this.GaugeForCount)
    Dim TimeDiffMs As Long
    TimeDiffMs = PerfGauge(GaugeMax)
    If this.PrintToImmediate Then
        Debug.Print "PerfGauge" & ":" & " - " & Format$(GaugeMax, "#,##0") & _
            " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
    End If
    PerfGaugeGet = TimeDiffMs
End Function

'''' ==================== TEST STUBS WRAPPERS ==================== ''''

Public Function Sub0ArgsDLLVBA(Optional ByVal DummyForCount As Long = -1, _
            Optional ByVal TargetType As TargetTypeEnum = TARGET_DLL) As Long
    Dim DummyMax As Long
    DummyMax = IIf(DummyForCount > 0, DummyForCount, this.DummyForCount)
    Dim CycleIndex As Long
    Dim Start As Single
    Start = Timer
    If TargetType = TARGET_DLL Then
        For CycleIndex = 0 To DummyMax
            DummySub0Args
        Next CycleIndex
    Else
        For CycleIndex = 0 To DummyMax
            DummySub0ArgsVBA
        Next CycleIndex
    End If
    Dim TimeDiffMs As Long
    TimeDiffMs = Round((Timer - Start) * 1000, 0)
    Dim Source As String
    Source = "Sub0ArgsDLLVBA/" & Array("DLL", "VBA")(TargetType)
    If this.PrintToImmediate Then
        Debug.Print Source & ":" & " - " & Format$(DummyMax, "#,##0") _
            & " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
    End If
    Sub0ArgsDLLVBA = TimeDiffMs
End Function

Public Function Sub3ArgsDLLVBA(Optional ByVal DummyForCount As Long = -1, _
            Optional ByVal TargetType As TargetTypeEnum = TARGET_DLL) As Long
    Dim Src() As Byte
    Src = this.Src
    Dim Dst() As Byte
    Dst = this.Dst
    Dim SrcLen As Long
    SrcLen = this.SrcLen
    Dim DummyMax As Long
    DummyMax = IIf(DummyForCount > 0, DummyForCount, this.DummyForCount)
    Dim CycleIndex As Long
    Dim Start As Single
    Start = Timer
    If TargetType = TARGET_DLL Then
        For CycleIndex = 0 To DummyMax
            DummySub3Args Dst(0), Src(0), SrcLen
        Next CycleIndex
    Else
        For CycleIndex = 0 To DummyMax
            DummySub3ArgsVBA Dst(0), Src(0), SrcLen
        Next CycleIndex
    End If
    Dim TimeDiffMs As Long
    TimeDiffMs = Round((Timer - Start) * 1000, 0)
    If this.PrintToImmediate Then
        Debug.Print "Sub3ArgsDLLVBA" & ":" & " - " & Format$(DummyMax, "#,##0") _
            & " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
    End If
    Sub3ArgsDLLVBA = TimeDiffMs
End Function

Public Function Fnc0ArgsDLLVBA(Optional ByVal DummyForCount As Long = -1, _
            Optional ByVal TargetType As TargetTypeEnum = TARGET_DLL) As Long
    Dim Result As Long
    Dim DummyMax As Long
    DummyMax = IIf(DummyForCount > 0, DummyForCount, this.DummyForCount)
    Dim CycleIndex As Long
    Dim Start As Single
    Start = Timer
    If TargetType = TARGET_DLL Then
        For CycleIndex = 0 To DummyMax
            Result = DummyFnc0Args
        Next CycleIndex
    Else
        For CycleIndex = 0 To DummyMax
            Result = DummyFnc0ArgsVBA
        Next CycleIndex
    End If
    Dim TimeDiffMs As Long
    TimeDiffMs = Round((Timer - Start) * 1000, 0)
    If this.PrintToImmediate Then
        Debug.Print "Fnc0ArgsDLLVBA" & ":" & " - " & Format$(DummyMax, "#,##0") _
            & " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
    End If
    Fnc0ArgsDLLVBA = TimeDiffMs
End Function

Public Function Fnc3ArgsDLLVBA(Optional ByVal DummyForCount As Long = -1, _
            Optional ByVal TargetType As TargetTypeEnum = TARGET_DLL) As Long
    Dim Src() As Byte
    Src = this.Src
    Dim Dst() As Byte
    Dst = this.Dst
    Dim SrcLen As Long
    SrcLen = this.SrcLen
    Dim Result As Long
    Dim DummyMax As Long
    DummyMax = IIf(DummyForCount > 0, DummyForCount, this.DummyForCount)
    Dim CycleIndex As Long
    Dim Start As Single
    Start = Timer
    If TargetType = TARGET_DLL Then
        For CycleIndex = 0 To DummyMax
            Result = DummyFnc3Args(Dst(0), Src(0), SrcLen)
        Next CycleIndex
    Else
        For CycleIndex = 0 To DummyMax
            Result = DummyFnc3ArgsVBA(Dst(0), Src(0), SrcLen)
        Next CycleIndex
    End If
    Dim TimeDiffMs As Long
    TimeDiffMs = Round((Timer - Start) * 1000, 0)
    If this.PrintToImmediate Then
        Debug.Print "Fnc3ArgsDLLVBA" & ":" & " - " & Format$(DummyMax, "#,##0") _
            & " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
    End If
    Fnc3ArgsDLLVBA = TimeDiffMs
End Function

'''' ==================== PERFORMANCE TEST STUBS ==================== ''''

Private Sub DummySub0ArgsVBA()
End Sub

Private Sub DummySub3ArgsVBA(ByRef Destination As Byte, _
            ByRef Source As Byte, ByVal Length As Long)
End Sub

Private Function DummyFnc0ArgsVBA() As Long
    Dim Result As Long
    Result = 10241024
    DummyFnc0ArgsVBA = Result
End Function

Private Function DummyFnc3ArgsVBA(ByRef Destination As Byte, _
            ByRef Source As Byte, ByVal Length As Long) As Long
    Dim Result As Long
    Result = 10241024
    DummyFnc3ArgsVBA = Result
End Function
```

The runner instantiates the DllPerLib class, sets repetition counts, and calls individual test members of DllPerLib performing secondary averaging.

**DllPerfRun.bas**

```vb
'@Folder "DllManager.Demo.Custom and Extended DLL.DLL Call Performance"
Option Explicit


Private Sub Runner()
    Dim GaugeMax As Long
    GaugeMax = 10 ^ 9
    Dim DummyMax As Long
    DummyMax = 10 ^ 7
    
    Dim PerfTool As DllPerfLib
    Set PerfTool = DllPerfLib.Create(DummyMax, GaugeMax)
    
    Dim TimeDiffMs As Long
    Dim LoopIndex As Long
    With PerfTool
        .TogglePrint
        
        Dim AverageCountGAU As Long
        Dim AverageCountDLL As Long
        Dim AverageCountVBA As Long
        AverageCountGAU = 20
        AverageCountDLL = 2
        AverageCountVBA = 10
        '''' ========== PerfGauge ========== ''''
        TimeDiffMs = 0
        For LoopIndex = 1 To AverageCountGAU
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs + .PerfGaugeGet
        Next LoopIndex
        If AverageCountGAU > 0 Then
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs / AverageCountGAU
            Debug.Print "PerfGauge" & ":" & " - " & Format$(GaugeMax, "#,##0") & _
                " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
        End If
        DoEvents
        '''' ---------- PerfGauge ---------- ''''
    
        '''' ========== Sub0ArgsDLLVBA ========== ''''
        TimeDiffMs = 0
        For LoopIndex = 1 To AverageCountDLL
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs + .Sub0ArgsDLLVBA(, TARGET_DLL)
        Next LoopIndex
        If AverageCountDLL > 0 Then
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs / AverageCountDLL
            Debug.Print "Sub0ArgsDLLVBA/DLL" & ":" & " - " & Format$(DummyMax, "#,##0") & _
                " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
        End If
        DoEvents
        
        TimeDiffMs = 0
        For LoopIndex = 1 To AverageCountVBA
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs + .Sub0ArgsDLLVBA(, TARGET_VBA)
        Next LoopIndex
        If AverageCountVBA > 0 Then
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs / AverageCountVBA
            Debug.Print "Sub0ArgsDLLVBA/VBA" & ":" & " - " & Format$(DummyMax, "#,##0") & _
                " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
        End If
        DoEvents
        '''' ---------- Sub0ArgsDLLVBA ---------- ''''
    
        '''' ========== Sub3ArgsDLLVBA ========== ''''
        TimeDiffMs = 0
        For LoopIndex = 1 To AverageCountDLL
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs + .Sub3ArgsDLLVBA(, TARGET_DLL)
        Next LoopIndex
        If AverageCountDLL > 0 Then
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs / AverageCountDLL
            Debug.Print "Sub3ArgsDLLVBA/DLL" & ":" & " - " & Format$(DummyMax, "#,##0") & _
                " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
        End If
        DoEvents
        
        TimeDiffMs = 0
        For LoopIndex = 1 To AverageCountVBA
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs + .Sub3ArgsDLLVBA(, TARGET_VBA)
        Next LoopIndex
        If AverageCountVBA > 0 Then
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs / AverageCountVBA
            Debug.Print "Sub3ArgsDLLVBA/VBA" & ":" & " - " & Format$(DummyMax, "#,##0") & _
                " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
        End If
        DoEvents
        '''' ---------- Sub3ArgsDLLVBA ---------- ''''
    
        '''' ========== Fnc0ArgsDLLVBA ========== ''''
        TimeDiffMs = 0
        For LoopIndex = 1 To AverageCountDLL
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs + .Fnc0ArgsDLLVBA(, TARGET_DLL)
        Next LoopIndex
        If AverageCountDLL > 0 Then
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs / AverageCountDLL
            Debug.Print "Fnc0ArgsDLLVBA/DLL" & ":" & " - " & Format$(DummyMax, "#,##0") & _
                " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
        End If
        DoEvents
        
        TimeDiffMs = 0
        For LoopIndex = 1 To AverageCountVBA
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs + .Fnc0ArgsDLLVBA(, TARGET_VBA)
        Next LoopIndex
        If AverageCountVBA > 0 Then
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs / AverageCountVBA
            Debug.Print "Fnc0ArgsDLLVBA/VBA" & ":" & " - " & Format$(DummyMax, "#,##0") & _
                " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
        End If
        DoEvents
        '''' ---------- Fnc0ArgsDLLVBA ---------- ''''
    
        '''' ========== Fnc3ArgsDLLVBA ========== ''''
        TimeDiffMs = 0
        For LoopIndex = 1 To AverageCountDLL
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs + .Fnc3ArgsDLLVBA(, TARGET_DLL)
        Next LoopIndex
        If AverageCountDLL > 0 Then
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs / AverageCountDLL
            Debug.Print "Fnc3ArgsDLLVBA/DLL" & ":" & " - " & Format$(DummyMax, "#,##0") & _
                " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
        End If
        DoEvents
        
        TimeDiffMs = 0
        For LoopIndex = 1 To AverageCountVBA
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs + .Fnc3ArgsDLLVBA(, TARGET_VBA)
        Next LoopIndex
        If AverageCountVBA > 0 Then
            TimeDiffMs = TimeDiffMs / AverageCountVBA
            Debug.Print "Fnc3ArgsDLLVBA/VBA" & ":" & " - " & Format$(DummyMax, "#,##0") & _
                " times in " & TimeDiffMs & " ms"
        End If
        DoEvents
        '''' ---------- Fnc3ArgsDLLVBA ---------- ''''
    End With
End Sub
```

#### Test results

I compiled x32 and x64 versions of the DLL and the C-client with MSYS/MinGW toolchains on Windows with no optimization (-O0), ran tests on each pair, and used the two DLL's to run tests from Excel 2002/VBA6/x32 and Excel 2016/VBA7/x64 respectively. I ran DllPerfRun.Runner multiple times, discarded results that were much slower than the rest, and calculated average timings. Table 1 shows a representative subset of results.

**Table 1. Time in seconds required for completion of 10<sup>9</sup> repetitions.**

[image: Results]

##### C-client timings

The leftmost column of Table 1 contains the PerfGauge timing. While I am not examining the disassembled code (which is a prudent thing to do), an empty unoptimized C-language For loop should require at least three machine instructions:

- increment the loop variable,
- compare the loop variable with the target,
- perform a conditional jump.

On a 2.2 GHz multi-core processor with dynamic frequency adjustment (Intel Core i7-8750H @2.2GHz), the number of 2.1 s for 10<sup>9</sup> repetitions, therefore, appears to be qualitatively reasonable. The second column shows the timing for calling DummySub0Args from the C-client (see DummySub0ArgsGauge routine). I do not have sufficient experience to explain why the numbers in the second column are lower. However, I am more concerned about the results in the right half of the table.

##### VBA timings

The green cell highlights the efficiency of calling a DLL routine from VBA6/x32/Excel 2002. This number indicates that a DLL call taking no arguments and returning no value is only 5x times slower than the same call from a compiled C-client. Further, this call is 7x times faster than a native VBA call (rightmost column) with the same signature. When the called routine either takes arguments or returns a value, the difference is less pronounced. Still, with the other three implemented mock calls, the tendency is qualitatively similar.

The primary concern is the cell with an orange background, indicating that a single DLL call takes 2 microseconds under 2016/VBA7/x64 instead of 8 nanoseconds under VBA6/x32/Excel 2002.

Sources and precompiled binaries are available from the GitHub [repository](https://github.com/pchemguy/DllTools) and additional information - from GitHub [pages](https://pchemguy.github.io/DllTools/).

Comment: This is clearly good detailed research, but I think you would do better if you could make an even simpler minrepro and post it over on stack overflow. Something like _"Here is a no-op function written in C which can be compiled into a dll. It can be invoked like `this ...` from C and takes 1.6ns on average (`C profiling code`). Alternatively it can be invoked from VBA like `this ...` and takes 8ns in VBA6 32 bit, 1950ns in 64 bit VBA7 (`VBA profiling code`)"_. All this stuff about different dummy methods and dynamically loading the dll is added noise.

Comment: ... Or are you asking for a review of your profiling methodology rather than trying to work out why your 64 bit code is not performing as expected?

Comment: @Greedo Right, I posted a question on SO regarding the performance issue. I am also interested in feedback/review on my approach/code, which is why I posted it here and included all details. Another reason for adding the details is that this is not a standard approach, so I feel like providing a description is important.

Comment: @PChemGuy I get the slow performance on VBA7 x32 while on VBA7 x64 all dll calls are super fast as expected. The bitness is not necessarily related with the slow performance. It is rather the type of Antivirus/Firewall used in the system that seems to be causing performance issues. At least on my machines.

Comment: @CristianBuse, I do not have antivirus on the computer where I ran tests. I believe that the only security feature enabled is the Windows firewall. It appears that Microsoft screwed up something fundamental with VBA. When I run test code, Excel uses its core at 100% level for the entire period.

Comment: @PChemGuy Might be unrelated. I just posted a comment to your answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/270053/227582) so you can see how bad it is for me on x32 VBA7 when using ```RtlMoveMemory```

Comment: @PChemGuy Maybe my problem is completely different and makes API calls even slower on top of what you found already.

Comment: @CristianBuse, yes I see it. I tested RtlMoveMemory, and on VBA7/x-64, RtlMoveMemory is as slow as a dummy DLL call. I created dummy dll fixtures intentionally to make it as simple as possible. The fact that a dummy call rate matches that of the API call suggests that the problem is not about WinAPI, but specifically about DLL calls. Any Office extension may be affected, therefore!

Comment: @PChemGuy Yes, hence I spent an enormous amount of time to come up with that ByRef method for copying bytes. So, that I am not affected by Office version. As a side note, the [WeakRef](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/lazy-object-weak-reference/) you linked is leaking. Greedo found a very nice case when reviewing my old implementation [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245660/simulated-weakreference-class). There must be some safety in place so that VBA does not reuse the same memory location after deallocating a previous instance referred by the saved pointer.